# How to set proper version control for Ionic project

Tags: android, ios, git, version-control, ionic-framework

We're working in an app for Android/IOS and the team has at least 3 people working in the app code and who need to have the app running locally in their particular env, someone is developing over Mac OS to eventually build to iOS and the others are on Windows machines.

We've been experiencing problems with the Ionic project after installing ngCordova, some cordova plugins and the ionic-platform-web-client, the mac machine had the app running beautifully and the windows instances were broken complaining that: `Module 'ionic.service.core' is not available!`

We don't know which particular step caused the code inconsistency and after several hours of looking around to fix it we decided just to create a new Ionic project and copy our specific www code inside. Since we don't want that to happen again we need to figure a reliable method of keeping all platforms working right after we install a plugin or add an Ionic service.

Could this be accomplished only by gitignoring www/lib folder and platforms, and then running bower install in each dev machine after a new module have been added to the project? or is it more complex than that and we're omitting some important steps to allow the project collaboration without these kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put `platforms` in your `.gitignore`. I personally wouldn't be putting `www/lib` folder there, though.

Also, I would strongly advise that on all the machines where you're building the apps locally you have the same version of Ionic and Node.